# I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null even though element id defined

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I am new to Javascript and HTML.I am getting this exception even though I have element defined in HTML. Please can somebody help? I am trying to draw a shape(initially a circle) depending on the input fromuser like shape type, coordinates, width , colour etc and this I am doing using datalist in HTML. But not able to get value of datalist shape that is selected in javascript function "rendershape".

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Orchid School</title>
<body>

<form id="myForm" name="formName" onSubmit="rendershape();">
Enter a shape:<br>
<input list="shapes" id="shapeid" name="shapeName">
<datalist id="shapes">
<option value="Circle">
<option value="Square">
<option value="Rectangle">
<option value="polygon">
<option value="triangle">
</datalist> 
<br><br>

Enter X-coordinate:
<br><br>
<input list="xcoordinates" name="xcoName">
<datalist id="xcoordinates">
<option value="50">
<option value="75">
<option value="100">
<option value="150">
<option value="200">
</datalist>
<br><br>

Enter Y-coordinate:
<br><br>
<input list="ycoordinates" name="ycoName">
<datalist id="ycoordinates">
<option value="50">
<option value="75">
<option value="100">
<option value="150">
<option value="200">
</datalist>
<br><br>

Enter colour:<br><br>
<input list="color" name-"colorName">
<datalist id="color">
<option value="Red">
<option value="Blue">
<option value="Orange">
<option value="Black">
<option value="Green">
</datalist> 
<br><br>

Enter line width:  <br><br>
<input list="width" name="WidhtName">
<datalist id="width">
<option value="1">
<option value="2">
<option value="3">
<option value="4">
<option value="5">
</datalist> 
<br><br> 

</form>

<button onclick="rendershape()">Draw shape</button><br><br>
```

Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.

```
<script>
function rendershape()
{   
    document.write('IN JS');
    var shape= document.getElementById("shapeid").options.value;
    console.log(shape);
    document.write(shape);
    var xcoordinat=document.getElementById("xcoordinates").options.value;
    console.log(xcoordinates);
    var ycoordinate=document.getElementById("ycoordinates").options.value;
    console.log(ycoordinates);
    var width=document.getElementById("width").options.value;
    if(shape=='Circle')
    {
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(xcoordinat,ycoordinate,50,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try var shape= document.getElementById("shapeid").value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corret your code for below points and then try.

- You have no `myCanvas` element
- instead of `options.value` just use `value`
- remove `document.write`, it cleans your page, for debugging use `console.log`

  get help from [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_canvas.htm)

**update: i think [w3resource](http://www.w3resource.com/html5-canvas/) is best with it's visual explanation**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am now able to draw a circle!!! I removed document.write and it worked. Did not get the concept though...is it that once we use document.write, the execution/compilation of javascript stops ?

Comment: no, compilation doesn't stops. But once `document.write` is executed, it clears out whole document, so your `js,html,css` everything will be cleaned, so no next line to execute. thus it looks like it's stopped.

Answer (score 4):

For first you execute this: `document.write('IN JS');`, after that your document contains only `IN JS`, you wipe other elements. After that, element with id `shapeid` is not exist.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me after `document.write` no so that line `document.getElementById("shapeid").options.value` throw the error

Comment: @shyammakwana.me shapeid disappears after document.write

Answer (score 0):

Please look at your code carefully, You need to put '=' instead of '-'

```
<input list="color" name="colorName">
```